# Python XMLParser : When is data() method called

Tags: python, elementtree

I am learning Python, and have some difficult understanding the xml parser (ElementTree - XMLParser) behavior.

I modified the example in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser.feed)

```
class MaxDepth:                     # The target object of the parser
    path = ""
    def start(self, tag, attrib):   # Called for each opening tag.
        self.path += "/"+ tag
        print '>>> Entering - ' + self.path
    def end(self, tag):             # Called for each closing tag.
        print '<<< Leaving - ' + self.path
        if self.path.endswith('/'+tag):
            self.path = self.path[:-(len(tag)+1)]
    def data(self, data):
        if data:
            print '... data called ...'
            print data , 'length -' , len(data)
    def close(self):    # Called when all data has been parsed.
        return self
```

It prints the below output

```
>>> Entering - /a
... data called ...

length - 1
... data called ...
   length - 2
>>> Entering - /a/b
... data called ...

length - 1
... data called ...
   length - 2
<<< Leaving - /a/b
... data called ...

length - 1
... data called ...
   length - 2
>>> Entering - /a/b
... data called ...

length - 1
... data called ...
     length - 4
>>> Entering - /a/b/c
... data called ...

length - 1
... data called ...
       length - 6
>>> Entering - /a/b/c/d
... data called ...

length - 1
... data called ...
       length - 6
<<< Leaving - /a/b/c/d
... data called ...

length - 1
... data called ...
     length - 4
<<< Leaving - /a/b/c
... data called ...

length - 1
... data called ...
   length - 2
<<< Leaving - /a/b
... data called ...

length - 1
<<< Leaving - /a
<__main__.MaxDepth instance at 0x10e7dd5a8>
```

My questions are

1. When is the data() method called.
2. Why is it called twice before the opening tag
3. I could not find api document to get more details on `data` method. Where can I find a javadoc like api reference for `XMLParser` class.

Comment: In case your use doesn't require event parsing, it is easier to work with `.parse()` http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html . Otherwise his event example might help : http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html#watching-events-while-parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to modify your data method like so:

```
def data(self, data):
    if data:
        print '... data called ...'
        print repr(data), 'length -' , len(data)
```

you'll see why there are multiple calls to the data method; it is called for every line of text data between the tags:

```
>>> Entering - /a
... data called ...
'\n' length - 1
... data called ...
'  ' length - 2
>>> Entering - /a/b
... data called ...
'\n' length - 1
... data called ...
'  ' length - 2
<<< Leaving - /a/b
... data called ...
'\n' length - 1
... data called ...
'  ' length - 2
>>> Entering - /a/b
... data called ...
'\n' length - 1
... data called ...
'    ' length - 4
# ... etc ...
```

The XMLParser methods are based on the [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) parser.

In my experience, any streaming XML parser will treat text data as a series of chunks and you have to concatenate any and all data events together until you hit the next starttag or endtag event. Often the parser breaks up chunks at whitespace boundaries but that is not a given.